# How do I approach a first order ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How does one solve $t^{2}x'-2tx=t^{5}$, $x(0)=0$ ?

If I seperate it by dividing by $t^{2}$, I will miss out the solution when $t=0$ ?

And if I seperate it should I then look at different cases when $t>0$ and $t<0$ ?

I seperated it and obtained $x'-\frac{2}{t}x=t^{3}$, $t\neq 0$. And then obtain that $(e^{-2ln|t|}x(t))'=\frac{t^{3}}{|t|^{2}}$.

For $t>0$ it has solution $x(t)=\frac{t^{4}}{2}+ct^{2}$. The initial condition $x(0)=0$ should always be satisfied then or? Does this mean that there is infinitely many solutions for $t>0$? And what about the cases when $t=0$ or $t<0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $t\ne0$, you can integrate with

$$\frac{x't^2-2tx}{t^4}=\left(\frac x{t^2}\right)'=t$$

then

$$\frac x{t^2}=\frac{t^2}2+C$$ and

$$x=\frac{t^4}2+Ct^2.$$

For $t=0$, the equation vanishes so that you have no information on $x'$. But by continuity, the solution $x(0)=0$ holds.